# How to use ModelBuilder to convert, insert, and finally delete in one operation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, modelbuilder

I'm working on ArcGIS Server, ArcMap and ArcCatalog

In ArcCatalog I've two databases (Temp.gdb and main.gdb) so I need a ModelBuilder model that :

- Convert CAD dwg file to Geodatabase (or dataset)
- insert all data from 1st geodatabse to the second one (main) and
- then delete all data from the first geodatabase (temp.gdb)

How can I do that with ModelBuilder or a script please the three operations must work in synchronisation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "one operation/in synchronization".  It sounds like you just need to export features from one geodatabase to another.  What type of CAD data are you working with?  DWG, DXF?

Comment: I mean in one model builder. Type of CAD data is DWG files. Thank you enough

Comment: Why do you need to import and then move the data?  Why not just import to the second GDB in the first place.  This could be done with just the CADToGeodatabase_conversion tool in the Arc Toolbox.  However, if it is truly necessary, I have provided a script that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script solution for you.  I'm not understanding why it is necessary to import and then move, but if it is necessary this will do it.

```py
import arcpy, os, sys
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inDWG = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
GDB1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
GDB2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
annoRef = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  #Reference Scale for Annotation (1000, 2000, 5000, 12000, etc.)

out_dataset_name = ((((((str(inDWG).split("\\"))[-1]).replace(" ", "_")).replace(".DWG", "")).replace(".dwg", "")) + "_FCDS")

arcpy.AddMessage(str(out_dataset_name))

arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(inDWG, GDB1, out_dataset_name, annoRef)

newFCDS = os.path.join(GDB1, out_dataset_name)

arcpy.env.workspace = GDB1

spatRef = arcpy.Describe(inDWG).spatialReference

arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(GDB2, out_dataset_name, spatRef)

for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets(str(out_dataset_name), "Feature"):
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('', '', fds):
        pathName = os.path.join(GDB2, out_dataset_name, fc)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management((os.path.join(GDB1, out_dataset_name, fc)), pathName)

arcpy.Delete_management(newFCDS)
```

I don't have an immediate solution for doing the same thing in model builder but I would think that this is more efficient.